# How to set kmix default volumes?

Tags: kubuntu, kmix

I have a strange problem with Kmix.
I want to record TV streams, this is already working. But with every restart, Kmix mutes the recording device. 
Because this, the tv recording program (mencoder & v4l2) canot record any sound (records from Line-in).

If i turn up the recording volume in Kmix, sound is recorded.

How can i set the default volume in Kmix? 
I have the "Restore volumes at startup" box checked, but record level is always muted at every boot. Sometimes the playback, too. If i uncheck it, reboot, and check again, and reboot, nothing changes.
I have googled a lot, but i have found nothing :S

I can agree with command line solutions, which i put in startup, or something, too...

I'm using Kubuntu 11.10

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem, and there is solution. I don't think that it is good idea or something like that but it's working for me.

1. Set levels in your mixer you want to restore at startup
2. Do this in the command line:

> ```
> alsactl store
> ```

3 . And put this simple script in autostart (as script):

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> for i in `seq 1 20`;
>  do
>   sleep 1
>   alsactl restore
>  done
> ```

(I don't know what change levels at startup, but if just execute 'alsactl restore' or 'sleep 10 && alsactl restore' it does not work)